# string is not printing in c++ outside the a for loop

Tags: c++, string, c++11, output, stdstring

I've tried to separate A-Z character in a given string using c++ but the separated string is not  printing in the output but if I shift the "cout" statement inside the for loop it printing the characters. I don't know why its happen. please let me know if I've done any mistake.

my code

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;    //number of test cases

    while(t--)
    {
        string s,a,n;
        int j=0,k=0;
        char temp;

        cin>>s;      //getting string

        for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
        {

            if(s[i]>=65 && s[i]<=90)       //checking for alphabets
            {
                a[j]=s[i];
                j++;
                cout<<a[j-1]<<endl;
            }

            else
            {
                n[k]=s[i];
                k++;
                cout<<n[k-1]<<endl;
            }

        }

        cout<<endl<<a<<endl<<n;       //this line is not printing
     }
}
```

Comment: Compile a debug version and run the program in your favorite debugger. The debugger will tell you what's wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String `a` is empty after initialization (i.e. it has length `0`). So you can't access/write any character using `a[j]`, because this writes beyound the string's current bounds and yields undefined behaviour.

use...

```
a.push_back(s[i]);
```

to append a character at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Since `a` is empty at the beginning and, as other answer says, you are writing beyond the string's current bounds, you can resize it to the size of `s` by doing the following:

```cpp
a.resize(s.size());
```

and, once you are done with the work, reduce its capacity to fit the actual size:

```cpp
a.shrink_to_fit();
```

This way you won't have memory reallocations that you might have when using `std::string::push_back`.

Comment: can I use s.length() inspite of s.size(). does both conveys the same meaning?

Comment: Yes, these are synonyms

Comment: while using shrink_to_fit it showing error - [Error] 'std::string' has no member named 'shrink_to_fit' does I need to include any library

Comment: @SarweshArivazhagan it compiles just fine. Check it out here https://godbolt.org/z/o9jf5K

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use `isupper()` function in your first `if` condition.
But first you have to initialize s[i] into `char` variable at first `for` loop and add `#include<cctype>` library. Like this:

> char c = s[i];
>
> if(isupper(c)){
> code
> }